# How to extract the text using XPath between tag and some end tag

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I have given the following HTML. The class names are always the same. Only the text between the tags varies and has different length and content.

```
<a>
    <span class="xxx">Not this text <span class="yyy">not this text</span> <span class="zzz">This is</span> the required text <q class="aaa">this not</q></span>
</a>
```

How do I extract the content between the tag with class "zzz" and the end of the line but the element with class "aaa" should **not** included in the result? Is it possible?

The element with class "aaa" may exists or not:

```
<a>
    <span class="xxx">Not this text <span class="yyy">not this text</span> <span class="zzz">This is</span> the required text</span>
</a>
```

The expected result should be:

```
This is the required text
```

Also the part "the required text" may exists or not:

```
<a>
    <span class="xxx">Not this text <span class="yyy">not this text</span> <span class="zzz">This is</span></span>
</a>
```

so the result should be:

```
This is
```

I try this in PHP using DOMXPath.

Comment: What is the parent element of those `span` nodes? That's where you need to be looking.

Comment: Currently its a <a>-tag around all the stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath solution :

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<a><span class="xxx">Not this text <span class="yyy">not this text</span> <span class="zzz">This is</span> the required text</span></a>
XML;
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$elements = $xpath->query('//text()[parent::*[not(@class="aaa")]][preceding::span[@class="yyy"]][normalize-space()]');
foreach($elements as $element)
echo $element->nodeValue;
```

Output :

```
This is the required text
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with XPath, necessarily, but here is a way you could do it without XPath.

```php
function walk(DOMNode $node, $skipParent = false) {
    if (!$skipParent) {
        yield $node;
    }
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $n) {
            yield from walk($n);
        }
    }
}

$html = <<<'HTML'
<span class="xxx">
    Not this text
    <span class="yyy">not this text</span>
    <span class="zzz">This is</span>
    the required text
    <q class="aaa">this not</q>
</span>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$count = 0;
foreach(walk($dom->firstChild) as $node) {
    if (!($node instanceof DOMText) && $node->hasAttribute('class') && $node->getAttribute('class') === 'xxx') {
        foreach(walk($node) as $n) {
            if (isset($content)) {
                $count++;
            }
            if (!($n instanceof DOMText) && $n->hasAttribute('class') && $n->getAttribute('class') === 'zzz') {
                $content = $n->textContent;
            }
            if (isset($content) && $n instanceof DOMText && $count == 2) {
                $content .= " " . $n->textContent;
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($content);
```

This gives you the desired result whether or not the `"the required text"` part is there.